# Iterate array of arrays in reverse and subtract following subarray values from current subarray values

Tags: php, arrays, math, multidimensional-array, subtraction

I have a dynamic multidimensional array like this:

```
$myarray = array(
            array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 70, 
                2 => 19,
                3 => 0
            ),
            array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 24,
                2 => 14
            ),
            array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 15,
                2 => 11,
                3 => 0
            ),
            array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 15,
                2 => 27,
                3 => 0
            )
        );
```

I need to loop through the subarrays and overwrite the current values of each subarray to represent the difference between the original value and the following value with respect to the subarray keys.

This describes the arithmetic desired on each subarray element (the value after the `=` is the new desired value):

```
$myarray = array(
            array(
                0 => 0 - 0 = 0
                1 => 70 - 24 = 46
                2 => 19 - 30 = -11
                3 => 0 - 0 = 0
            ),
            array(
                0 => 0 - 0 = 0
                1 => 24 - 0 = 24
                2 => 14 -(-16) = 30
                3 => 0 - 0 = 0
            ),
            array(
                0 => 0 - 0 = 0
                1 => 15 - 15 = 0
                2 => 11 - 27 = -16
                3 => 0 - 0 = 0
            ),
            array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 15,
                2 => 27,
                3 => 0
            )
        );
```

I tried to do something, but it is not what I need and it contains errors:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($myarray as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $k_key => $v_values) {
        $calc = $values[$k_key+1]-$v_values;
        array_push($new_array , $calc);
    }
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: @mickmackusa i posted it , but as i said it contains error and is not what i want.

Comment: May I ask what php version you are using?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes for sure, 5.5

Comment: In input array, is `array(0 => 0, 1 => 70, 2 => 19, 3 => 0)` the previous subarray of subarray `array(0 => 0, 1 => 24, 2 => 14)` ?

Comment: @Daniel1147  array(0 => 0, 1 => 24, 2 => 14) is the next array after array(0 => 0, 1 => 70, 2 => 19, 3 => 0) in array **$myarray** whats means, that i have 4 subarray in **$myarray**

Comment: So the number of subarray elements is unknown in your project?

Comment: Ok got it. You start from the bottom and substract the values, going up the array of arrays and substract every time the result of the previous substraction...  So myarray[3] = myarray[3] - myarray[4].  The myarray[2] = myarray[2] - (myarray[3] - myarray[4]).  And so on ...

Comment: @mickmackusa is the same array and i want to the end array values from $myarray  - previous array from end and the sum minus previous array. I hopw you understand what i mean

Comment: @Nic3500 yes, but as i said i have an dynamic array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start from 2nd last subarray, and loop toward the start
2. Find the longer array's length of the two targeted arrays
3. Iterate and perform subtractions / declarations
4. declare/overwrite new values as they are encountered

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XdO1X))

```
$myarray = [
    [0, 70, 19, 0],
    [0, 24, 14],        // note missing 4th element
    [0, 15, 11, 0],
    [0, 15, 27, 0]
];

for ($i = count($myarray) - 2; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    $max = max(count($myarray[$i]), count($myarray[$i+1]));
    for($k = 0; $k < $max; ++$k) {
        $myarray[$i][$k] = ($myarray[$i][$k] ?? 0) - ($myarray[$i+1][$k] ?? 0);
    }
}

var_export($myarray);
```